# NoReverseMatch at /basic_app/user_login/

Tags: django

Register works but login doesn't for some reason even though I've rechecked the template tagging properly.
I'm using a custom login model, not using the admin authentication model.

this is the at basic_app/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from basic_app import views

app_name = 'basic_app'

urlpatterns = [
    url('register/',views.register,name='register'),
    url('user_login/',views.user_loginPls,name='user_login'),
]
```

and code at base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'basic_app:register' %}">Register</a></li>

                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                      <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                      <li><a href="{% url 'basic_app:user_login' %}">Login</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            {% block body_block %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and code at view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basic_app.forms import UserForm,UserProfileInfoModelForm

#imports
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
#changed from django.core.usrlresolvers to django.urls
#cant use reverse as it has been deprecated
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request,'basic_app/index.html')

@login_required
def special(request):
    return HttpResponse('your logged in nice!!!')

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

def register(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoModelForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()

            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoModelForm()

    return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered})



def user_loginPls(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse('ACCOUNT NOT ACTIVE')
        else:
            print('SOMEONE TRIED TO LOGIN AND FAILED')
            print("Username: {} and password: {}".format(username,password))
            return HttpResponse('INVALID LOGIN DETAILS')
    else:
        return render(request,'basic_app/loginhtml.html',{})
```

[image]

I can't figure out this error, any help would be appreciated.

> I'm running Django 2.0 btw

Comment: There's no any url that matches `/basic_app/user_login/`.
Try changing `/user_login/` into `/basic_app/user_login/`, check if the problem solved.

Comment: do you call this url somewhere else? because Django says `error at line 0` I think the current issue is not in `base.html`, maybe in some included files or extended files

Comment: omg thank you for that point Lemayzeur, i messed up my template tagging else where

Answer (score 1):

the error is in your *login.html* file.
In the form section, the action should take `action="{% url 'user_login' %}"` and not `action="{% url 'basic_app/user_login' %}"`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the error comes from the login.html file. Within the form section, the action is supposed to take this template tag action="{% url 'basic_app:user_login' %}" method="post"> and not action="{% url 'basic_app/user_login' %}"

I guess you've figured it out